# Error on changing url with latest Sveltekit

Tags: localhost, vite, sveltekit

Since the August changes to Sveltekit which resulted in a Vite-dictated http://localhost:5173/ I have been changing it in package.json with

```json
"scripts": {
        "dev": "vite dev --port 3000",
```

And this has been working well, but as of today I get the following error:

```
Not found: /app
Error: Not found: /app
    at resolve (file:///C:/sveltekit-load/sveltekit%20supabase%20CRUD/cookie/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:256:13)
```

which is:

```
line 256   error: new Error(`Not found: ${event.url.pathname}`),
```

So I have to change the Supabase URL to 5173. Not the end of the world but it's an annoyance that
I would rather not have. Has anybody any quick and easy remedy for changing the url to localhost:3000 that doesn't generate errors.
Many thanks.

Comment: I am still using the `--port` argument without any issues (have been using it for a long time)...